# after bootup,crashing

Tags: android, database, sqlite, service, boot

My application is using a bootup service.In the service i have to get values from a database,but the app is crashing as it tries getting the values...

The logcat error is listed below...........

> 01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.android.antitheft.MyService: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2969)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2087)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at com.android.antitheft.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:69)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2959)
>   01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240):  ... 10 more

Thanx in advance..............

my service.java //file

```
package com.android.antitheft;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

SQLiteDatabase myDB;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@OnCreate1111");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      myDB = MyService.this.openOrCreateDatabase("antitheft", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        Cursor cursor1 = myDB.query("SimSerial", null, null, null, null, null, null);
     cursor1.moveToLast();
        //cursor1.moveToFirst();
        String ss1 = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("simno"));
        Toast.makeText(this, "FROM DATABASE: SIM SERIAL "+ss1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        cursor1.close();
        myDB.close();



//          cursor2.moveToNext();
//          String num2 = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("secure"));
//          
//          cursor2.moveToNext();
//          String num3 = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("secure"));  

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String ss=tm.getSimSerialNumber();

        Log.v("SERVICE", ss);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started : SIM SERIAL "+ss, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.v("StartServiceAtBoot", "StartAtBootService -- onStartCommand()");          



        if(ss.equals(ss1))
        {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

//              sms.sendTextMessage("5556", null, "message", null, null);

            Toast.makeText(this, "INSIDE iffffffffffff ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             myDB = MyService.this.openOrCreateDatabase("antitheft", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cursor2 = myDB.query("SimSerial", null, null, null, null, null, null);

            cursor2.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor2.isAfterLast() == false) {
                String num1 = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("secure"));
                sms.sendTextMessage(num1, null, "message", null, null);
                cursor2.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor2.close();

            myDB.close();

//              sms.sendTextMessage(num1, null, "message", null, null);  
//              sms.sendTextMessage(num2, null, "message", null, null);
//              sms.sendTextMessage(num3, null, "message", null, null);
            }

//          else
//              
//          {
//              SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
//              sms.sendTextMessage("5556", null, "message", null, null);
//              
//              Toast.makeText(this, "INSIDE elseeeeeeeeeeeeee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//          }


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) 
    {



        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for this myself...

the error,rather say;my mistake in coding was that i was supposed to use `moveToNext()` instead of `isAfterLast()`

Answer (score 5):

When you Create Cursor from the Database you have to first check for both `(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())`. In your case if there is no any data available then it will create a problem.

so before you use Cursor add the condition

```
if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
//write your code here
}
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1
>   failed

Normally this error you will get if you are trying to read a column value from the cursor but that column is not exists in the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

From the error it seems that you are fetching some content from the `Database` in the `Cursor`. But fetching the content from the `Cursor` you need to `point the Cursor to the first row` that your cursor contains. So you need to apply `cursor.moveToFirst();` to get it working, if this is the case. Else you should post the full source or the code where you feel its crashing.

Answer (score 3):

The error says that you are trying to receive the string from the column with index -1 which is WRONG.
Columns are enumerated starting from 0. As google's doc says about Cursor.getColumnIndex(String name), it returns -1 if the column with "name" name doesn't exist.
Check the line 69 of your MyService.java file:

```
String num1 = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("secure"));
```

I think there is no "secure" column in your database. Verify your database.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the database located? And are you sure you have your permissions set? Also, could you post the code to your MyService Class?

Comment: Jade Byfield i have posted my service class