# what is this database error?

Tags: android, database

i want to know what this error is?

> 01-03 22:49:50.722: ERROR/CursorWindow(240): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1

Comment: can you please upload the code ?

Comment: Just Check your Columns and Rows, where you've use this by cursor. Otherwise, explain more with some code & Logcat.

Comment: Hello... provide me query which you are trying to execute.

Comment: check this question this error is based on this question[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722853/after-bootup-crashing/8722896#8722896

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always use

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```

code while fetching data from cursor

hope this may helps