# Application crash on bootup.

Tags: android, service, boot

I am here to ask a question based on the following link, 
      This was the question asked by my friend can someone answer the question below.
  [after bootup,crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722853/after-bootup-crashing/8722896)

log cat error is as shown below:

```
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.android.antitheft.MyService: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2969)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2087)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at com.android.antitheft.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:69)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2959)
01-03 22:19:46.097: E/AndroidRuntime(240): ... 10 more
```

Comment: What does the line of code at line 69 in MyService.java do? Just posting logcat isn't helpful - we need to see the code, paricularly that line and any code before it.

Comment: Can you please post your service class?

Comment: check the link i have described the i have provided the service class

Comment: Are you asking anything different to the linked question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use movetonext in the cursor in database

Answer (score 1):

I already commented in original thread.
Will re-phrase it here:

The error says that application tries to access DB column with index -1. I believe it happens because the application receives invalid index from Cursor.getColumnIndex("secure"); 
Check the database, I think there is no "secure" column there.